# Opening XML/GMD resource in QGIS

Tags: qgis, xml

I have this web resource XML description. From what I saw, it's ArcGIS API format, but I can't find anything else.

What standard is it, and is it possible to connect to this resource in QGIS?

http://www.metadados.geo.ibge.gov.br/geonetwork_ibge/srv/por/xml.metadata.get?uuid=b3c58b5e-10d5-4026-a4f5-dab1393054a8

Comment: That URL returns only `The requested operation could not be performed.

BadParameterEx : fname`.

Comment: @user30184 updated the link. Should work now.

Comment: this is a link to some metadata not to the actual data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata#Geospatial_Applications), are you asking how to access the data described here or how to read these metadata ?

Comment: `From what I saw, it's ArcGIS API format`, no it's ISO 19139 XML metadata describing a dataset that can be accessed/downloaded (according to the metadata) from https://censo2010.ibge.gov.br/apps/atlas/#/

Comment: `What standard is it` it's `<gmd:metadataStandardName>
<gco:CharacterString xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv">ISO 19115:2003/19139</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:metadataStandardName>`

Comment: There's nothing here to suggest any ESRI product.  Metadata catalogue is provided by GeoNetwork, and it appears that there's a GeoServer WMS for some data like: `https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/CGEO/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=CGEO:C04_DensidPop2010_PR&styles=&bbox=-54.6193046381684,-26.7171220078991,-48.0235374355348,-22.5162951649053&width=518&height=330&srs=EPSG:4674&format=application/openlayers`